# FB.api POST with OK result, but no effect on FB

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

this is my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  console.log('FB.init');
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    status: true,
    xfbml:  true,
    cookie: true,
    oauth:  true,
    version: 'v2.5'
   });
};

(function(d, s, id)
  { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function fbLogin() {    
    console.log('FB.getLoginStatus');
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
    {   console.log('response: ' + response);
        console.log('status:   ' + response.status);
        if (response.status == 'connected') 
        {   accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; }
        else 
        {   FB.login(function(response)
            {   if (response.status == 'connected') 
                {   accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; }
                else {   alert("Bye!"); }
            },             {scope:'publish_stream,user_photos,friends_photos,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags'});
        }
    });
}

function fbFeedShare()
{   console.log('fbFeedShare');
    fbLogin();
    console.log('FB.api POST');
    FB.api("/me", "POST", { body: "body", message: 'My message is ...' },
    function(response) 
    {   console.log('response: ' + response);
        console.log('status:   ' + response.status);
        if (response.hasOwnProperty("error"))
            console.log('error:    ' + response.error.message);
        if (!response || response.error) { console.log("POST ERROR"); }
        else  { console.log("POST OK"); }
    });
}
```

And now when I call **fbFeedShare** in console log every looks OK:

```
FB.init
fbFeedShare
FB.getLoginStatus
    response: [object Object]
    status:   connected
FB.api POST
   response: [object Object]
   status:   undefined
   POST OK
```

but no visible results on Facebook

What is wrong?

Comment: you should not copy very old code. some of those permissions are deprecated since years. take a look at the official docs to find out which permissions you need.

Comment: also, debug the response objects.